# SearchView com MVP

Tags: android

Estudando o padrão MVP, refatorei uma atividade que lista os dados de produtos, apenas uma simples lista mais que faço a filtragem de dados, as informações vem do banco de dados interno e a filtragem era feita na lista do adaptador.

Eu acredito que consegui aplicar o conceito até chegar o momento de refatorar a filtragem então me veio a questão? por ser uma filtragem dos dados da lista deverei implementar a filtragem no presenter? no Modelo?

O Adapter não refatorei ainda foi ai que surgiram as questões, e ele tem lógica ou seja o próprio filtro é uma lógica então não pode ficar no adapatador então onde ficaria esta lógica alguém pode me ajudar como disse eu revisei tudo e acredito que para atender ao padrão só falta isto.

segue os códigos

```
interface ListaProdutosMVP {

   interface View {
       void atualizaLista();
       void showToastError(String mensagem);
       void showToastInfo(String mensagem);
       void showToastWarning(String mensagem);
       void showToastSuccess(String mensagem);
   }

   interface Presenter {
       void recuperarProdutos();
       void atualizaLista(ArrayList<Produto> produtos);
       ArrayList<Produto> getProdutos();
       Context getContext();
   }

   interface Model {
       void recuperarProdutos();
   }
```

Implementação do Modelo

```
class ProdutoModel implements ListaProdutosMVP.Model {

   private DAOProduto dao ;
   private ListaProdutosMVP.Presenter presenter;

   public ProdutoModel(ListaProdutosMVP.Presenter presenter) {
       this.presenter = presenter;
       this.dao = new DAOProduto(presenter.getContext()) ;
   }

   public Produto BuscaporId(int Id) { return dao.buscarPorId(Id); }

   public List<Produto> buscarTodos() {
       return dao.buscarTodos();
   }

   @Override
   public void recuperarProdutos() {
       ArrayList<Produto> lista = (ArrayList<Produto>) dao.getListaOrdenada();
       presenter.atualizaLista( lista );
   }
}
```

Implementação do presenter

```
class ListaProdutosPresenter implements ListaProdutosMVP.Presenter {

   private ArrayList<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
   private ListaProdutosMVP.Model model;
   private ListaProdutosMVP.View view;

   public ListaProdutosPresenter(ListaProdutosMVP.View view){
       this.view = view;
       this.model = new ProdutoModel(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void recuperarProdutos() {
      model.recuperarProdutos();
   }

   @Override
   public void atualizaLista(ArrayList<Produto> lista) {
      produtos.clear();
      produtos.addAll(lista);
      view.atualizaLista();
   }

   @Override
   public ArrayList<Produto> getProdutos() {
       return produtos;
   }

   @Override
   public Context getContext() {
       return (Context) view;
   }
}
```

Implementação da View ( Activity )

```
class ListaProdutosActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements ListaProdutosMVP.View {

   private static final String TAG = "ListaProdutos";
   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   private ProdutosAdapter adapter;

   private ListaProdutosMVP.Presenter presenter;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_produtos);
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");

       if(presenter == null){
          presenter = new ListaProdutosPresenter(this);
       }

       presenter.recuperarProdutos();
       adapter = new ProdutosAdapter(this, presenter.getProdutos());
       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_lista);
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new 
          LinearLayoutManager(this);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       int id = item.getItemId();

       if(id == android.R.id.home){
           finish();
       }
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void atualizaLista() {
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

e por ultimo o adapter e nele eu iniciei a filtragem dos dados e percebi que isto é lógica então devo mudar esta lógica para o presenter ou modelo?

```
class ProdutosAdapter extends 
     RecyclerView.Adapter<ProdutosAdapter.MyViewHolder> 
        implements Filterable {

   private ListaProdutosActivity activity;
   private ArrayList<Produto> items;
   private ArrayList<Produto> mFilteredList;

   public ProdutosAdapter(ListaProdutosActivity activity, ArrayList<Produto> items) {
       this.activity = activity;
       this.items = items;
       this.mFilteredList = items;
   }

   @Override
   public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

       View v = LayoutInflater
            .from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.model_produto_item, viewGroup, false);
       return new MyViewHolder(v);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.setDados(mFilteredList.get(position));
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return mFilteredList.size();
   }

   // Lógica 
   @Override
   public Filter getFilter() {

       return new Filter() {
           @Override
           protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

               String charString = charSequence.toString();

               if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                   mFilteredList = items;
               } else {
                   ArrayList<Produto> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                   for (Produto p : items) {

                       if (p.getNome().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ||
                            p.getEan_13().toLowerCase().contains(charString) 
                            ||   p.getDescricao().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {
                        filteredList.add(p);
                       }
                   }

                   mFilteredList = filteredList;
               }

               FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
               filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
               return filterResults;
           }

           @Override
           protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
               mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Produto>) filterResults.values;
               notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       };
   }

   class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                      implements View.OnClickListener {

       public TextView txtNome;
       public TextView txtValor;
       public TextView txtStatus;

       public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

           txtNome = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
           txtValor = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtValor);
           txtStatus = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
       }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Produto p = mFilteredList.get(getAdapterPosition());
           activity.selectItem(p);
       }

       public void setDados(Produto produto) {
           txtNome.setText(produto.getNome());
           txtValor.setText( LetrasUtils.monetarioMask(produto.getValor()));
           txtStatus.setText("Ativo: " + produto.getAtivo());

       }
   }
```

}

Comment: De forma simples, o filtro tem que ser feito no modelo, e você deve passar pra ele a query ou qualquer outra informação que ele necessitar para filtrar. O presenter é apenas a ponte, pois a responsabilidade de recuperar as informações é do modelo, e nada mais justo que ele ser o responsável por filtrar.

Comment: Olá Wakim obrigado pelo retorno, meu caro mais o modelo quando a atividade iniciou ele já forneceu na integra os registros obtidos do banco, pelo adapter o recyclerview tem sua lista, a filtragem ( manipula dados sem sombra de dúvida ) mais apenas filtra os elementos da lista, lista esta que eu coloquei no presenter por isto fico com a duvida se não poderia continuar esta etapa no presenter.

Comment: Supondo que seu modelo é simples, tudo bem, é válido. Mas em casos reais, você pode ter um Modelo que consome dados de uma API ou então de um banco local, ou até de ambos. Filtrar no presenter poderia não ser uma boa escolha, tudo depende do contexto.

Comment: Na verdade estou obtendo a lista para o adapter do SQLite (Local) é isto que o Modelo faz para obter a lista, e passa ela para o presenter onde tenho uma instancia private ArrayList<Produto> produtos, eu não pretendo fazer uma nova busca no banco quando estiver fazendo uma filtragem (Search), caso fosse sim eu iria novamente solicitar ao modelo uma nova lista.

Comment: Ter a filtragem no Presenter ainda vá(apesar de eu achar que o Model é que deveria prover os dados filtrados) agora o Model ter uma referência ao Presenter(`public ProdutoModel(ListaProdutosMVP.Presenter presenter)`) é que não.

Comment: Olá ramaral bom dia, sim o presenter pode ter uma referencia a view public ListaProdutosPresenter(ListaProdutosMVP.View view), e o model não pode ter referencia ao Presenter? porque pode explicar ou sugerir?, desta forma eu acredito que consegui implementar o padrão existe comunicação bidirecional entre a view e presenter,  presenter e model

Comment: Isso é imposto pelo padrão: Model <- Presenter <-> View. O Presenter "conhece" o Model e a View, a View "conhece" o Presenter. O  Model não tem qualquer conhecimento dos outros dois. Veja este [post](http://www.tinmegali.com/pt/model-view-presenter-mvp-no-android-introducao/).

Comment: Saca só estes aqui https://guides.codepath.com/android/Architecture-of-Android-Apps#migrating-to-clean-architecture, e este outro aqui http://konmik.com/post/introduction_to_model_view_presenter_on_android/ e ainda mais este outro aqui http://thefinestartist.com/android/mvp-pattern

Comment: e se olhares o post que me indicaste ele ainda tem a parte 2 e 3 (chegaste a ler), na parte 2 podemos ver public MainModel(MainMVP.RequiredPresenterOps mPresenter) não vi problemas em como eu implementei o padrão.

Comment: OK, `MainMVP.RequiredPresenterOps` é uma *interface* não é o Presenter. Não tinha reparado que você também estava a usar uma interface.